# Get object name as string (not class name)

Tags: javascript

I researched this but only found articles (or threads) about getting the class name

For example:

```
const john = {
    firstName: this.constructor.name,
    lastName: 'smith'
}

console.log(john.firstName) // john
```

How can I access the object name as string so it outputs 'john' ?

Comment: You can't. The variable name "john" is not part of the object in any way; objects don't have names unless you add some sort of "name" property yourself.

Comment: Interesting thank you very much

Comment: Thanks it's similar, not exactly what I was looking for but I see it's not possible as well probably for the same reason